# unable css on window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

EDITED: the first one was already solved but this is the project that I've been working on the one that i deleted was just a test, anyways the answer on the previous post before i edit this was solved, i applied the same solution but can't seem to be solve the problem. can someone tell me the difference why this won't work compare to the previous one, thanks :).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
    <script src="src/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    @media print {
      .active {
        background-color: #ff0000;
      }
    }
    .card-default {
        color: #333;
        background: linear-gradient(#fff,#ebebeb) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        font-weight: 600;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;    
    }
    .signature {
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    input {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0;
    var meal_allow_table = document.getElementsByClassName("meal_allow");
    var days = [];



    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("table").find("input").attr("disabled", true);

      $('input[name="inlineRadioOptions"]').change(function () {
        $("table").find("input").removeAttr("disabled");
        if ($('#pay_period_from').prop('checked')) {
          $('.first-period').addClass('active');
          $('.second-period').removeClass('active');
        }else if ($('#pay_period_to').prop('checked')) {
          $('.second-period').addClass('active');
          $('.first-period').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    });

    function printForm() {
      window.print();
    }



</script>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h3>LINA GROUP OF COMPANIES</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search text-gold"></i>
                            <b>Meal and Overtime Authorization Form</b>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id=hideDiv>
                    <form action="index.php" method="POST">       
                        <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Company:</label>
                                            <input id="inputCompany" name="company" type="text" class="form-control"  />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-4">
                                        <!--  <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Dept/Location:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        </div> -->
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">

                                    <!-- <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    </div> -->
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Pay Period:</label>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-check col-lg-2"></div>
                                                <div class="form-check col-lg-5">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="pay_period_from" value="option1">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Day 1 - 15 </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-check col-lg-5">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="pay_period_to" value="option2">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Day 16 - 31 </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>      
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" name="btnPrint" id="btnPrint" onclick="printForm()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Print</button>
                                            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" href="#" id="btnToTop"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> Top</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                            <div id="div">
                                <table class="table" style="width:100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;" >Date</th>
                                        <th colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">OT Field</th>
                                        <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">Purpose of Overtime</th>
                                        <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">OT hours</th>
                                        <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">Meal Allow</th>
                                        <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">Boss</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2">() rarbk & file ()</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>a
                                        <th style="max-width: 40px">From</th>
                                        <th style="max-width: 40px">To</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">December</th>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width:10%" class="first-period">1</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%" class="second-period">16</td>
                                        <td class="timepicker_from" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="timepicker_from" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="pot" style="width: 250px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="pot" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input class="meal_allow" value="0" type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="pot" style="width: 200px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="first-period">2</th>
                                        <td class="second-period">17</td>
                                        <td class="timepicker_from" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="timepicker_from" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="pot" style="width: 250px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="textarea" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="ot" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input class="meal_allow" value="0" type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="boss" style="width: 200px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="total"><b>TOTAL</b></th>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td id="total"></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <div style="margin-top: 15px" class="footer">
                                    <p>Note: Pls Encircle corresponding meal allowance and always indicate covered pay period.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
  <input type="text" id="inputMultiDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the majority (afaik) of browsers disable backgrounds when printing html.  In chrome, after clicking the button and the print dialog appears, click on "more settings" -> "background graphics"

Comment: I don't know what to tell you... I literally copy/pasted your code and it worked fine for me

Comment: i mark your answer correct already, but i tried the same solution u gave me on the previous code that i  have, but when i applied it to my code, still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@media` rule to the CSS file

```
@media print {
  .print-para {
     background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

add this class when printing the clicking the button

```
$('#btnChange').click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('print-para');
  window.print();
});
```

Enable background display in the print preview settings in your browser

```
Print Preview > More Settings > Background Graphics
```